# ASP.Net core NullReferenceException was not handled by the user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

**Not a Duplicate**: See the comment and answer to this question.

I am almost new to ASP.net Core development. I am building a sample web api with MySql as my database.

My Book model:

```
public class Book
    {   
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public Book()
        {

        }
    }

    public class WebAPIDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public WebAPIDataContext(DbContextOptions<WebAPIDataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

Book Repository:

```
public class BookRepository: IBookRepository
    {
        private readonly WebAPIDataContext _db;

        public BookRepository(WebAPIDataContext db) {
            _db = db;
        }

        public Book CreateBook(Book book) {
            _db.Books.Add(book);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return book;
        }

        public void DeleteBook(long id)
        {
            Book book = GetBook(id);
            if (book != null) {
                _db.Books.Remove(book);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public List<Book> GetAllBooks()
        {
            return _db.Books.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }

        public Book GetBook(long id)
        {
            return _db.Books.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
        }

        public void UpdateBook(long id, Book book)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IBookRepository
    {
        List<Book> GetAllBooks();
        Book GetBook(long id);
        Book CreateBook(Book book);
        void UpdateBook(long id, Book book);
        void DeleteBook(long id);
    }
```

And Book controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBookRepository _books;

        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult GetAllBooks()
        {
            List<Book> books = _books.GetAllBooks();
            return Ok(books);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetBook(long id)
        {
            Book book = _books.GetBook(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(book);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateBook([FromBody] Book book)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            Book createdBook= _books.CreateBook(book);

            return CreatedAtAction(
                nameof(GetBook), new { id = createdBook.Id }, createdBook);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult UpdateBook(long id, [FromBody] Book book)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {
                _books.UpdateBook(id, book);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (EntityNotFoundException<Book>)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteBook(long id)
        {
            _books.DeleteBook(id);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

When I do a POST request from Swagger to create a new book it gives me `NullReferenceException` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well I tried handling null as suggested at this post but didn't help.

Comment: Where do you assign _books in the controller class to the implementation? Right now it doesn't have a initialized state at runtime.  And it doesn't happen unless you do it in the constructor with DI assuming is the route you were attempting to go.   not a Dupe... just a misunderstanding of why in his case.

Comment: This is my very first attempt with ASP.net Core and I was following (https://joonasw.net/view/building-a-basic-web-api-on-asp-net-core) this tutorial. I basically tried the same logic as his but with different model. Perhaps you could give me the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first case to work you needed to have

```
services.AddScoped<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();
```

in `ConfigureServices` method located in the `startup.cs`

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
   public BooksController(IBookRepository books){
       _books = books;
   }
   ...
```

Now this assumes you hooked up your IBookRepository to be included in the container for Asp.NET Core in the startup class.

*IF NOT* then this is what you are missing!

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
   public BooksController(){
       _books = new BookRepository();
   }
```

If you have never worked with Dependency Injection before this I suggest you read up on it, also goes by IOC (inversion of control).

Comment: Okay let me try this!

Comment: Yes the first solution worked! Thanks a lot! I basically overlooked the tutorial, it was mentioned in it.